# Aligning title and buttons using Bootstrap 5 on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align 1 title and 2 buttons this way:

On mobile :
title: center, one row
button1 and button2: width100%, one above the other
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALFV6.png)

Right now it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUNlx.png)

On desktop:
title: right
button1 and button2 small

Right now looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUAae.png)

I am using bootstrap 5.3 and this is what i did so far:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <h2 class="card-title fw-bold">Calendar (<i>not connected to google</i>)</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-flex btn-primary btn-block" data-kt-calendar="connect_to_google">
            <i class="ki-double-arrow-back fs-2"></i>Connect to Google</button>

            <button class="btn btn-flex btn-primary btn-blockt" data-kt-calendar="add">
            <i class="ki-duotone ki-plus fs-2"></i>Add Event</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try please like his, it should work:

```
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
                  <h2 class="card-title fw-bold">Calendar (<i>not connected to google</i>)</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-sm-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-flex btn-primary btn-block" data-kt-calendar="connect_to_google">
                    <i class="ki-double-arrow-back fs-2"></i>Connect to Google</button>

                  <button class="btn btn-flex btn-primary btn-blockt" data-kt-calendar="add">
                    <i class="ki-duotone ki-plus fs-2"></i>Add Event</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

You will use flex-direction row for big devise and flex-direction: column for small one.
You will use this rule for common row and also for col with buttons inside.
For row we will also use justify-content-between to provide expected horizontal alignment, and align-items-center - for vertical alignment.

Comment: The example works as i expected. Now i can't make buttons smaller and have a little bit of padding. Btw, where i can find this explained step by step? I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Put each button inside of div, then you will be able to work with the size of buttons.

Comment: `m-5` works, but 'mr-5' don't ... i don't understand why -> https://playcode.io/1491878

Comment: As you told, you are using Bootstrap 5.3. In this case you need to use "e" (for end) instead of "r" (for right). So to make mr-5 in Bootstrap 5.3 you need to right me-5. Here is Bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thank you. Turns out that `l` and `r` were changed with `b` and `e`